# Prove the associativity property for orientation-preserving isometries of the Euclidean plane

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I just started learning group theory and I have to prove the following theorem:

> If $\mathrm{I}_{+}(\mathbf{E})$ is the set of all complex functions of the form $f(z)=az+b$ where $a,b,z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $|a|=1$, then
> $$\forall a,b,c\in\mathrm{I}_{+}(\mathbf{E}):\, a*(b*c)=(a*b)*c$$
> where $*$ is a functional composition on $\mathrm{I}_{+}(\mathbf{E})$.

**What I tried:**

I know that functional composition is a binary operation on $\mathrm{I}_{+}(\mathbf{E})$. But I keep getting different results, neither of which seems to lead to the desired result.

Associativity can be represented in the functional notation as follows: $f(f(a, b), c) = f(a, f(b, c))$. So
$$f: a,b\mapsto az+b$$
$$f(f(a,b),z)=f(az+b,z)=(az+b)z+z=az^2+bz+z$$
$$f(a,f(b,z))=f(a,bz+z)=az+bz+z.$$
These are equal iff $z^2=z$, but that means that either $z=0$, or $z=1$. So this approach doesn't seem to be correct.

Since multiplying by $a\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|a|=1$ has the effect of a rotation, I tried to look at it from a different perspective: It says that a translation and then a rotation should have the same effect as a rotation and then translation.
$$\text{Translation, then rotation:}\, z\mapsto z+b\mapsto a(z+b)=az+ab$$
$$\text{Rotation, then translation:}\, z\mapsto az\mapsto az+b$$
These are equal iff $a=1$, so this doesn't seem to be the right way either.

Comment: Your theorem is ill-stated because "where $*$ is **a** binary..." is vague ("a" is unclear). It should say more clearly that $\ast$ denotes composition of functions.

Comment: @YCor You're right, let me correct that.

Comment: If (as your question asserts) this is a group, then associativity is implied. "Show that this is a group by proving associativity" is the real question. Pedantry only ever seems to count in pure mathematics, but in pure mathematics, pedantry is what you are fighting for. [Written by a "recovering" pure mathematician]

Comment: @MarkBennet I completely agree; I wanted to give the set "a familiar name", so that people know what's this question about directly from the title. But it could have been reworded better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement of the problem seems almost designed to confuse the reader. First they use $a$ and $b$ as elements of $\mathbb C$, when writing $f(z) = az + b$, and then they use them to represent elements of $\mathrm{I}_{+}(\mathbf{E})$ when writing out the condition for associativity. No wonder it's not working.

In particular, $f(f(a, b), c) = f(a, f(b, c))$ doesn't even make sense -- $f\in \mathrm{I}_{+}(\mathbf{E})$ is not a function of two variables. Let's set things up properly and see how that works.

Let's let $f$, $g$, and $h$ be elements of $\mathrm{I}_{+}(\mathbf{E})$. That means that

$$\begin{align}f(z) &= az +b \\
g(z) &= cz + d \\
h(z) &= rz + s
\end{align}$$

where $a,b,c,d,r,s \in \mathbb C$ (and $|a| = |c| = |r| = 1$). Now the question didn't state explicitly what binary operation on $\mathrm{I}_{+}(\mathbf{E})$ you were supposed to use, but as you noticed, when functions are around "composition" is the obvious one to use. So what you have to prove is

$$ (f \circ g) \circ h = f \circ (g \circ h)$$

At this point we can feel a bit silly, because function composition being associative is pretty basic, and we've probably assumed it dozens of times before, but I'd guess they want you to grind it out in this case, so, letting $z$ be a variable that ranges over $\mathbb C$, we have to show that

$$ ((f \circ g) \circ h)(z) = (f \circ (g \circ h))(z)$$

Now, using the definition of function composition and the expressions for $f$, $g$, and $h$ above, you can explicitly compute both sides, and they should end up being equal. (Note: LeeMosher has worked this all out in his answer, but you might want to try writing it out for yourself. You might come across this some time in the future and writing it out should help you recognize it when you see it again.)

Two notes:

- We have not shown that $\mathrm{I}_{+}(\mathbf{E})$ is closed under $\circ$, i.e. that if $f, g \in \mathrm{I}_{+}(\mathbf{E})$, then $f\circ g \in \mathrm{I}_{+}(\mathbf{E})$. They didn't explicitly ask for that, but they also didn't explicitly say to use function composition. Morally, since we chose to use composition, I feel that we owe the reader a demonstration of that (it's not hard), but it's up to you (and your grader).
- I think there's a super slick way of showing all this by representing your functions as $2 \times  2$ matrices, and showing that function composition is just matrix multiplication, but I'll leave that as an answer for someone else to provide.

Comment: I see now; the way they use $a,b$ for both the function $f(z)$ and the set $\mathrm{I}_{+}(\mathbf{E})$ confused me a lot (by the way, I've already proved that $\mathrm{I}_{+}(\mathbf{E})$ is closed under functional composition; that was the previous exercise). Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Also, if $f(z)=az+b$ for $a,b,z\in\mathbb{C}$, $a\ne 0$ and $|a|=1$, then the function rotates $z$ through an angle of $\operatorname{Arg}a$ about the origin, and translates the result by $b$. What does the associativity property of $\mathrm{I}_{+}(\mathbf{E})$ say in the context of geometry? I'd like to know, because it seems that I misinterpreted it as the fact that rotation and then translation is the same as translation and then rotation.

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is not the function $\langle a, b\rangle\mapsto az+b$ but rather $z\mapsto az+b$. A better notation would be to use subscripts, i.e. $f_{a,b}(z) = az+b$. So you want to show that $f_{a, b}\circ(f_{c, d}\circ f_{e, f}) = (f_{a, b}\circ f_{c, d})\circ f_{e, f}$ which is true since composition of functions is associative.

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting up the associative law correctly. What you have to do is to take three elements $f,g,h \in \mathrm{I}_{+}(\mathbf{E})$, each of which has its own formula with its own independent constants:
\begin{align*}
f(z) &= az+b \\
g(z) &= cz+d \\
h(z) &= kz+l
\end{align*}
The operator $*$ is just  function composition:
$$f * g(z) = f(g(z))
$$
Comment: The usual symbol I see for function composition is $f \circ g$, but I'll stick with your symbol $f * g$.

So, work out the formula for $g * h(z)$ and then substitute that for $z$ in the formula for $f(z)$:
$$g * h(z) = c(kz+l)+d = ckz + cl + d
$$
$$f(g * h(z)) = a(ckz + cl + d) + b = ackz + acl + ad + b
$$
Next, work out the formula for $f * g(z)$, and then substitute $h(z)$ for $z$ :
$$a(cz+d) + b = acz + ad + b
$$
and substitute in $h(z)$
$$ac(h(z)) + ad + b = ac(kz+l) + ad + b = ackz + acl + ad + b
$$

Comment: Hi Lee! It was nice to see you also having to deal with the confusion that setting $h(z) = ez +f$ would have caused.  I'm also curious to see which of our answers gets a better reception.